# Is there any way to use Foreach loop internal file counter to use it outside?

Tags: variables, ssis, foreach-loop-container

We know that Foreach loop task in control flow has some internal setting to look for files matching our requirement. For example if we configure Foreach Loop to look into C:\Temp\ folder to look for *.csv file and if there is no file, it won't even go inside the loop to do other task. It will return a message with some code saying that there was no file found inside it. 
My question is. Is it possible to capture this system variable (if it is and what it is called) and use this value to do some other task.

Thanks

Comment: To restate: in the event a foreach loop does not find a file, you want some alternative action taken?

Comment: Not really.. I want Foreach Loop to give a warning of not finding any file. But I want to use that variable to other task such send a mail using that variable

Comment: Foreach Loop *does* give a warning if no file found `FELC OpenReqs:Warning: The For Each File enumerator is empty. The For Each File enumerator did not find any files that matched the file pattern, or the specified directory was empty.`

Comment: So then when the Foreach loop doesn't find a file, is your desire that it still perform some of the tasks inside the data flow? Perhaps a picture of what your package looks like and what behaviour you would like would be of use. Use any of the free hosting sites and edit your question---it sounds like it could be an interesting one.

Comment: actually my next step would be outside FOREACH LOOP. Like sending email based on expression evalution.